# How would I mathematically describe the transformation of 4 2D points to 4 2D points on the x/y axes?

Tags: python, transform, linear-algebra

(See the bottom of this question for an update)

I am by no means a math expert, so please forgive any missteps in terminology, etc.

In my application (Python), there is always a slightly unique space of possible input coordinates that can be described by a 4 sided polygon, an example of which is shown here (pre-adjusted to place the centroid directly over the origin):

[image: input coordinate space]

I want to figure out how to describe the transformation (or series thereof) that would transform that space to this constrained space:

[image: transformed coordinate space]

If I can find that transformation, then later, when I have an individual input coordinate come in from the user during the usage of the program, I will apply the same transformation to give me an individual coordinate value that will be constrained to the transformed coordinate space depicted in the last image.

To make that last part more clear, here is a graphic of what I'm describing, not to scale:

[image: user input transformation]

I am not terribly well versed in linear algebra (and maybe linear algebra isn't even the way to go?), so perhaps I am missing something obvious. My plan was as follows:

Let T be the transformation matrix I am looking for

Let A be the original matrix of coordinates

Let A_T be the transformed matrix of coordinates

**A_T = T * A**

Therefore, I thought that I would isolate T by saying:

**T = A_T * inverse(A)**

The problem is, A is not square, (as it contains 4 2D points), so I can't calculate its inverse.

Basically, I want to describe the transformation that takes (ax, ay) (bx, by) (cx, cy) (dx, dy) to (1, 0) (0, 1) (-1, 0) (0, -1) and I am out of ideas at the moment.

**Update**

I have been experimenting with an adaptation of @wychmaster's answer to this question here:

https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/12819/how-to-determine-transformation-matrix-for-an-object-given-a-graph

```
import numpy as np

x_all = [x - x_center for x in x_all]
y_all = [y - y_center for y in y_all]

# All x coordinates
x_all = [258.75, -401.25, -741.25, 883.75]
# All y coordinates
y_all = [156.25, 171.25, -188.75, -138.75]

# original coordinate matrix
A = np.array([x_all, y_all, [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, .9999999]])
# transformed coordinate matrix
A_T = np.array([[1, 0, -1, 0], [0, 1, 0, -1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]])

# Solve for T where A_T = T @ A
T_1 = np.linalg.solve(A.transpose(), A_T.transpose()[:, 0])
T_2 = np.linalg.solve(A.transpose(), A_T.transpose()[:, 1])
T_3 = np.linalg.solve(A.transpose(), A_T.transpose()[:, 2])
T_4 = np.linalg.solve(A.transpose(), A_T.transpose()[:, 3])
T = np.array([T_1, T_2, T_3, T_4])

# Check to see if T @ A = A_T
print((T @ A).round(decimals=3))

# Multiply each original coordinate pair of the original coordinate space to see if they are correctly transformed
for i in range(4):
    print((T @ np.matrix([[x_all[i]], [y_all[i]], [1], [1]])).round(decimals=3))
```

And this actually *almost* works, but with a problem!

You'll notice on line 12, there is some terrible hackiness I put into the very last element of the last row of the A matrix that I added in order to get this to run; otherwise Python rightfully complains that this is a singular matrix. When I multiply T @ A, it correctly spits out A_T. However, when I multiply each vector individually, which is akin to how I'll be using this matrix in the program (transforming individual input coordinates to the constrained space), the .999999 value screws up the last coordinate, here's the output from the for loop that prints the multiplication results:

```
[[1.]
[0.]
[1.]
[1.]]

[[-0.]
[ 1.]
[ 1.]
[ 1.]]

[[-1.]
[ 0.]
[ 1.]
[ 1.]]

[[ 1.577]
[-2.104]
[ 1.   ]
[ 1.   ]]
```

As you can, see, it *almost* works, just need a way around adding that arbitrary value into the last row.

In

Comment: Do you know that your transformation actually can be expressed by a matrix multiplication? Not all transformations of 2D point sets can - for example a translation cannot.

Comment: You need may need scaling, translating, rotating or shearing transforms https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix.

Comment: @slothrop OP should use an affine transform which can easily handle translations

Comment: Please provide the coordinates for your "Input coordinate space" example

Comment: @Reinderien Hey there. So, an example coordinate space would be this: (487.5, 200) (-412.5, 200) (-762.5, -200) (687.5, -200), however, this will be slightly different every time, so I would need a generalized way of doing the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

For an arbitrarily-sized point set, use `lstsq`. The transformation matrix will be approximate.

```py
import numpy as np

px_space = np.array((
    ( 487.5,  200),
    (-412.5,  200),
    (-762.5, -200),
    ( 687.5, -200),
))
px_space_augmented = np.hstack((px_space, np.ones((px_space.shape[0], 1))))

norm_space = np.array((
    ( 1,  0),
    ( 0,  1),
    (-1,  0),
    ( 0, -1),
))

T, *_ = np.linalg.lstsq(px_space_augmented, norm_space)
print(T)
```

```
[[ 8.06866953e-04 -8.06866953e-04]
 [ 2.34871245e-03  2.65128755e-03]
 [-1.91559047e-36 -2.77555756e-17]]
```

Comment: Hi Reinderien, thank you for taking the time to help me out! Unforunately, that solution doesn't seem to work for me. If I multiply T by the original px_space, the values are all over the place:

[[ 0.232 -0.494 -0.454  0.716]
 [ 1.675 -0.439 -2.321  1.084]
 [-0.    -0.     0.     0.   ]]

However, I have an approach that is almost working that I'll add to the bottom of my original question in a few minutes. Perhaps you can point me in the right direction there.

Comment: How are you multiplying? It should look like: `px_space_augmented @ T`

Comment: I was multiplying T @ px_space. If I use the augmented space and switch the order, as you suggested, it produces this:

[[ 0.863  0.137]
 [ 0.137  0.863]
 [-1.085  0.085]
 [ 0.085 -1.085]]

Comment: I just added updates with (almost) working code to the bottom of my original question.